# Changing file association creates malware false positive

Tags: installation, windows-10, inno-setup, malware, false-positive

I am trying to build an installer for my program using Inno Setup Compiler, but when I add the following lines to create a file association, the installer is detected and isolated by windows defender on Windows 10.

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".tgt";                             ValueData: "{#MyAppName}";          Flags: uninsdeletevalue; ValueType: string;  ValueName: ""
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}";                     ValueData: "Program {#MyAppName}";  Flags: uninsdeletekey;   ValueType: string;  ValueName: ""
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}\DefaultIcon";         ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0";           ValueType: string;  ValueName: ""
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}\shell\open\command";  ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1""";  ValueType: string;  ValueName: ""
```

Much searching has not yielded a result, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is Installer running in Admin mode? Providing credential to installer should tell Windows it is safe.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the script above. Do you get the problem if you use another "exe"?

Comment: Installer is running in an elevated mode (can't remember which at the moment will check later).

The problem was reproduced with different *.exe's 

Only by adding/removing these four lines was there any change on the test machine.

Comment: Additionally, the installer checks the current .net version, downloading a new one if appropriate, sets access privileges for the installed files and of course, installs an application.

This problem seems oddly limited to Windows 10 and in researching it, there seems to be a theme going on here - not that I **want** to bash Windows 10………